# Weird Numba 0.50 behaviour when using @jit

Tags: python, jit, numba

The following function works perfectly fine with Numba 0.38:

```py
@jit
def _ndiff(x):
    s = x.size
    r = np.empty(s, dtype=np.bool) 
    for i in range(1, s): 
        r[i] = x[i] - x[i-1] 
    return r

arr = np.array([True, True, True, False, False, False, False, True, True, True])

_ndiff(arr)

# > np.array([3, 7])
```

However, when using Numba 0.50 it outputs a quantity of errors:

```
./application.py:18: NumbaWarning: 
Compilation is falling back to object mode WITH looplifting enabled because Function "_ndiff" failed type inference due to: Unknown attribute 'type' of type array(bool, 1d, C)

File "application.py", line 23:
def _ndiff(x):
    <source elided>
    s = x.size
    r = np.empty(s, dtype=x.type) 
    ^

During: typing of get attribute at ./application.py (23)

File "application.py", line 23:
def _ndiff(x):
    <source elided>
    s = x.size
    r = np.empty(s, dtype=x.type) 
    ^

  @jit
./application.py:18: NumbaWarning: 
Compilation is falling back to object mode WITHOUT looplifting enabled because Function "_ndiff" failed type inference due to: cannot determine Numba type of <class 'numba.core.dispatcher.LiftedLoop'>

File "application.py", line 24:
def _ndiff(x):
    <source elided>
    r = np.empty(s, dtype=x.type) 
    for i in range(1, s): 
    ^

  @jit
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/core/object_mode_passes.py:177: NumbaWarning: Function "_ndiff" was compiled in object mode without forceobj=True, but has lifted loops.

File "application.py", line 22:
def _ndiff(x):
    <source elided>
    s = x.size
    ^

  warnings.warn(errors.NumbaWarning(warn_msg,
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/core/object_mode_passes.py:187: NumbaDeprecationWarning: 
Fall-back from the nopython compilation path to the object mode compilation path has been detected, this is deprecated behaviour.

For more information visit http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/deprecation.html#deprecation-of-object-mode-fall-back-behaviour-when-using-jit

File "application.py", line 22:
def _ndiff(x):
    <source elided>
    s = x.size
    ^
```

Basically it complains a lot about falling back to object mode because he's not happy with almost everything it finds here. Despite these warnings, testing the `@jit` function with a 1,000,000-size array gives absolute certainty in the fact that it's absolutely and definitely not running in object mode (it runs in a few microseconds despite these warnings while the pure Python version takes forever).

Is there something different to do with this version of Numba?